# Browsing website while a sticky audio player is playing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html5-audio

I am building a website in PHP, in which i want to show sticky audio player at website footer page. When any user play audio player it should continue to play even user click on any other page.

Player example should be like http://www.mixcloud.com

How to achieve this kind of player functionality. If any example available in PHP, it would be great.

Comment: looks like the site's using some complex JS & Ajax. A simpler way is to use frame, you can still control things in it, but simpler.

Comment: @rlatief could you please show me example how we can do that using frame?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hmm no :D I don't have the courage to put frameset sample codes without testing since I haven't been using it for a long time (I believe it's also deprecated but still available in HTML5). Do a search there should be lots of samples about how to create HTML frames. Then do a search about how to manipulate things in it by using (not too complex) JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to have a sticky audio/video player constantly playing while you browse the rest of a website, you need to use frames or asynchronous calls (Ajax).

Let's see how it can be done using Ajax. For the purpose of this example five files are needed as shown below. At this point, place all of them within a same directory.

index.html (the main file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Browsing and playing music</title>

<style type="text/css">
    #menu {overflow:hidden;margin:0px;padding:0px;list-style-type:none;}
    #menu > li {float:left;padding:5px;margin:5px;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

// This function will dynamically load all the needed content 
// url -> what to load; target -> where to place it on return

function load_content(url, target){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            target.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}

// In a real situation you may not want to change default behavior for all the
// links within a page - in that case, mark those link with a 'class-name' and loop 
// them using getElementsByClassName('class-name')

window.onload = function(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('A'), i;
    load_content('home.html', document.getElementById('content'));
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        (function(i){
            a[i].onclick = function(){
                load_content(a[i].href, document.getElementById('content'));
                return false;
            };
        })(i);
    }
};

</script>

</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- this div holds all the dynamic content -->
<div id=content></div>

<!-- player -->
<audio controls id="player">
    <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<p>This is the default page...</p>
```

about.html

```
<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>Something about us</p>
```

portfolio.html

```
<h1>Portfolio</h1>
<p>This is our portfolio. Isn't it gorgeous!</p>
```

contact.html

```
<h1>Contact</h1>
<p>Catch us if you can...</p>
```

And you'll need a song in .ogg or .mp3 format

---

In case we deal with dynamic files, the sample above should be slightly modified. In the example below only two files are needed.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Browsing and playing music</title>

<style type="text/css">
    #menu {overflow:hidden;margin:0px;padding:0px;list-style-type:none;}
    #menu > li {float:left;padding:5px;margin:5px;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function load_content(action, target){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "listener.php?action=" + encodeURIComponent(action);
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            target.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}

window.onload = function(){
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic'), i;
    load_content('home', document.getElementById('content'));
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        (function(i){
            a[i].onclick = function(){
                load_content(a[i].href, document.getElementById('content'));
                return false;
            };
        })(i);
    }
};

</script>

</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="home" class="dynamic">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about" class="dynamic">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio" class="dynamic">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact" class="dynamic">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- this div holds all the dynamic content -->
<div id=content></div>

<!-- player -->
<audio controls id="player">
    <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

listener.php

```
switch(isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : "default"){
    case "about":
        echo "about-content";
        break;
    case "portfolio":
        echo "portfolio-content";
        break;
    case "contact":
        echo "contact-content";
        break;
    default:
        echo "index-content";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Concerning the Javascript part, I would advice to use the HTML5 History API so that the URL changes in the browser despite the AJAX-loaded page content.

To do so, there is the very good [jQuery pjax plugin](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) that automates the HTML5 history API and that can replace the Javascript you wrote with just one line of code.

Comment: @MichaëlPerrin could you please implement the `HTML5 History API` and update the answer or add new ones?